# Implementing RecyclerView

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I am trying to implement `RecyclerView`, but it does not get imported in main activity.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.recycler_view;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);
    }

}
```

Please any one tell how I am going to import the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: did you write below code in gradle 
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'

Comment: @Madhur he is right. You need to add the following lines in dependicies block in your build.gradle belongs to your executor module which can be named as "app". Also dont forget to call rv.setLayoutManager(...). Otherwise your recycler view dosent work. :)

Comment: Refer These links [RecyclerView ](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) [RecyclerView ](http://www.exoguru.com/android/ui/cardview/custom-android-list.html)

Comment: Which IDE Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: How i am going to get gradle file i am using eclipse , is gradle file concept is also in while devloping in eclipse

Comment: check this tutorial post : http://wiki.workassis.com/android-recyclerview-example/

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add the following gradle dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
```